# Find archived entries in org-mode by properties within an archive file

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have an agenda file, and use the default archive file. So agenda.org and archive to agenda.org_archive for example. When archived, the items get archival properties

```
* DONE some task
:PROPERTIES:
:ARCHIVE_TIME: 2021-07-27 Tue 15:18
:ARCHIVE_FILE: ~/agenda.org
:ARCHIVE_OLPATH: Misc
:ARCHIVE_CATEGORY: notes
:ARCHIVE_TODO: DONE
:END:
```

I'd like to search for these using `org-tags-view`, with `ARCHIVE_TIME>"<+2w>"` for example. This works in my main agenda file if I toggle `org-agenda-archives-mode`, but I cannot get it to search the agenda.org_archive file. I have added this file to `org-agenda-text-search-extra-files`, but that doesn't help. In fact [this documentation](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html#searching-additional-files) says this "has no effect on other types of agenda commands, such as todo and tags/property searches".

So how can I search archives within an archive file?

---

Also, I have attempted by adding the archive file directly to `org-agenda-files`:

```
(setq org-agenda-files '("~/org"))
```

This directory contains both files, but this doesn't work either.

Comment: You probably want a custom agenda view that limits itself to just the archive file with a tags/properties search - see the doc string of `org-agenda-custom-commands` and the section "Custom Agenda Views" in the manual. BTW, in the code you show above, if that's all you are doing, then you are not doing anything: those two are no-ops (and there is an extra paren at the end; are you cribbing this from a `customize-variables` expression?)

Comment: You're right. I wasn't setting the variables in the way that I thought. I believe I am now and have updated the question accordingly. I will look into the "Custom Agenda Views". Thank you.

Comment: @theherk Have you figured out a solution?

Comment: @FredSchoen I did not, and I don't have the same workflow now, so I can't actually recall where I left off.